# WFFM "Parameter xml is null or empty" error on publishing

Tags: wffm

I installed WFFM and published `/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers` from master database to web database using publish subitems and related items option.

When I opened that item in website database in Form Designer, i got below exception.

> Parameter xml is null or empty

Any pointer would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Assembly , Column and Factory templates under the Folder Web Forms for Marketers are not published even when related items is checked at system level form item.

From Master databse select /sitecore/templates/Web Forms for Marketers and publish with "include subitems" option, then you will be able to see the form in Form Designer properly.